# Making my Azure website secure with SSL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I would like to improve the security of the transactions that occur on an Azure website I am developing by using an SSL certificate. However, I know very little about the subject. Azure seems to support SSL and I can get certificates from numerous authorities.

I only want to be able to get to the transactional stuff if the connection is secure. The main home/landing page of the site can be arrived at using http or https?

Where can I go to find out more about SSL and particularly how I incorporate it into Azure websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this sites

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/